Ingest config data from a new file found in folder
What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to kick off a child pipeline in Gitlab whenever a new file is found within a certain folder?  What we're trying to do is scale up our current approach to be less hard coded.
My thought was to create a front end web page where our customer can signup for our service. Once they are in the system, I generate the needed config data for the pipeline and dump it into our gitlab repo.
My hope is that when that file is found, somehow create the new pipeline from the config data in that new file and then kick it off.
This question seems to have some of what I'm looking for:
Create Gitlab CI job through for loop
But I'm not sure about how to absorb the config data from the new file
